# Is "this is different than before" valid US English for "this is different from before"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, american-english, north-american-english

I have many times heard James Rolfe and Mike Matei (the video content producers), who I believe both grew up in New Jersey or in the city Pennsylvania, say things such as:

> Blablabla. This is different than before. Blablabla.

Every time, it seems to me, a non-native English speaker, as if they should be saying "from" instead of "than". I'm pretty sure it's not valid formal British English at least, but I don't know about US English.

Maybe it's not even valid formal US English, but valid "talk speech"? Maybe it's even local slang in New Jersey or "Philly"?

Comment: Most Americans seem to have no qualms with this, if they're not pedants. In British English we tend to say 'different *to*' rather than 'different *than*' in informal speech.

Comment: @AeonAkechi As a speaker of British English I say "different from", never "different to".

Comment: @BoldBen I don't use 'different to' either, but it's undeniable that it's very common here.

Comment: @AeonAkechi True, but I don't think that either "from" or "to" is predominant. Unfortunately "different than" seems to be making headway, probably as a result of US media influence.

Comment: Related: [History of “different from”, “different to”, “different than”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/382004/history-of-different-from-different-to-different-than)